# How can I send and receive a char from one task to another task by using queue on FreeRTOS?

Tags: arduino, embedded, multitasking, freertos

When I try to send a variable from a task to another task, I can not receive anything with xQueueReceive. I'm using UART and Arduino Mega. I will send a char to Arduino, then Arduino will send this char to another device. But I can not get any result. Here is my code:

```
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>
#include <semphr.h>
#include <queue.h>

SemaphoreHandle_t xSerialSemaphore;
QueueHandle_t queue;

void TaskWrite( void *pvParameters );
void TaskRead( void *pvParameters );

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  if ( xSerialSemaphore == NULL )  
  {
    xSerialSemaphore = xSemaphoreCreateMutex(); 
    if ( ( xSerialSemaphore ) != NULL )
      xSemaphoreGive( ( xSerialSemaphore ) ); 
  }

  queue = xQueueCreate(15, sizeof(int));
  if (queue == NULL) {
    Serial.println("Queue can not be created");
  }
  // Now set up two Tasks to run independently.
  xTaskCreate
    TaskDigitalRead
    , "Read"  
    ,  256  
    ,  NULL
    ,  2  
    ,  NULL );

  xTaskCreate(
    TaskWrite
    , "Write"
    ,  256  
    ,  NULL
    ,  1  
    ,  NULL );
}

void loop()
{
  // Empty. Things are done in Tasks.
}

void TaskRead( void *pvParameters __attribute__((unused)) )
{
  int c = 0;
  for (;;) 
  {
    if ( xSemaphoreTake( xSerialSemaphore, ( TickType_t ) 5 ) == pdTRUE )
    {
      xQueueReceive(queue, &c, 1000);
      Serial.println(c);
      xSemaphoreGive( xSerialSemaphore );
    }

    vTaskDelay(1); 
  }
}

void TaskWrite( void *pvParameters __attribute__((unused)) )
{

  for (;;)
  {
    if ( xSemaphoreTake( xSerialSemaphore, ( TickType_t ) 5 ) == pdTRUE )
    {
     if(Serial.available()>0)
     {
      int c = Serial.read();
      Serial.print("I received ");
      Serial.println(c);
      xQueueSend(queue, (void *)&c, 1000);
     }

      xSemaphoreGive( xSerialSemaphore );
    }

    vTaskDelay(1);
  }
}
```

If I enable xQueueReceive line, I can not see anything on serial monitor.

Comment: You do not need a semaphore. Just fill the (thread safe) queue in one task/irq and read it from another. Read also the docs: https://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Queues.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there can be a breaking race condition if TaskRead takes the semaphore first while the queue is still empty. Why not simply block TaskRead in xQueueReceive ?
What’s the purpose of the semaphore at all ? If you really have to protect the Serial thing yourself better use a mutex around accessing Serial.